# Why calling Hide in a child form's FormClosing event handler hides the parent form?

Tags: c#, winforms, hide

When Form2 is closed, via it's X button, the Main form is sometimes hidden as well, but not always.  Often times the Main form is hidden after initial 'newForm' button click and other times many open-close operations are required before the Main form gets hidden on Form2's closing.  Why is this happening?  Why is it irregular?

This is a small test code for a larger application I'm working on.  In that application a thread continuously reads the network stream and when a particular message is encountered a modal form is displayed.  The user can close that modal form or it can be told to close itself by a different network message.  In this event, to give the user some time to view the data that the form is displaying I implemented a delayed form closing for that form.  When the form is running its delay closing code, another message can come in over the network that will open up a new instance of this form in which case, I observed, that once the timer of the original form runs out, the original form is left displayed until the new instance is closed.  Calling Hide in the FormClosing event handler closes the original form if more than one instances of it are running, but it has this side effect of hiding the entire application (the Main form) when the last instance of this form is closed, either by the user or by the delayed closing code.  And again, the entire application is not always hidden, but it does happen.

```
//Main form's 'newForm' button
private void btn_newForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.ShowDialog();
}   

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
    }
}
```

Update (from the application I'm working on):

The problem is shown visually below.  The top part of the picture, labeled "A", represents the situation where the first modal dialog (greyed out) was instantiated and it is in the process of being auto closed after 4 seconds have elapsed.  The second instance (blue window heading) is active and awaiting input.  In the lower part of the picture, labeled "B", the counter to closing of the first instance has completed, yet the first instance remains visible.  Adding Hide does not change picture "A" but picture "B" would only be showing the active modal dialog, which is what I want.  If Hide is not used and we have the case shown in "B", once the active modal dialog is closed the inactive dialog will disappear together with the active one, but no sooner.  At this time my main form will be hidden as well, sometimes.

[image: the problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main form doesn't get hidden, it disappears behind another window.  The flaw in your code is that for a brief moment *none* of your windows can get the focus.  Your main window can't get the focus, it got disabled by your dialog and won't get re-enabled until the dialog is fully closed.  Your dialog can't get the focus, you hide it.  So Windows goes looking for another window to give the focus to and can only pick a window owned by another application.  Like Visual Studio, nice and big so your main window is well covered by it.

Not sure what you are trying to do, it doesn't make sense to call Hide() since the dialog will close a couple of microseconds later.  Just delete the statement.

Comment: "since the dialog will close a couple of microseconds later"  the problem is that it doesn't (see Update with picture) if it did I would not need to bother with Hide.  I will think on what you said about the lost focus.

Comment: There's a drastic mismatch between the code snippet and the screen shots.  A bunch of code we can't see, I see no compelling reason to change my answer.  Odds that it is the problem I documented are still good.

Comment: When the main form "disappears" it's taskbar icon is depressed, if I click it then windows goes through its maximize followed by minimize animations and the main form is minimized. Clicking it yet again will show the main form.  So losing focus is the most likely scenario.

Comment: You are right that the snippet is not the code that's behind the screenshot dialogs, but in both cases Hide produces the described behavior of the parent form disappearing.  Having said that, your answer seems to be the correct one.  Now, how to restore the focus...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am right but maybe you forgot to add `e.Cancel = true;` to your closing event.

Second, I think using a modal form is only usefull when you expect an action like OK or CANCEL from user, that is where DialogResults comes handy. It sounds strange if this happens time to time not all the time! maybe you can try like this:

```
//Main form's 'newForm' button 

//Define form in your mainform 
private Form2 f;

private void btn_newForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
        if(f != null) { f.Show(); return; }

        f = new Form2()
        f.FormClosing += delegate { f.Hide(); };         
        f.Show(); 
}
```

Comment: Modal is needed as it needs to interrupt the main form and there is a decision made in that dialog that will determine the next course of action.  I don't think e.Cancel = true will be helpful here as I do want the dialog to close.

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is quite old, but I recently had to look for answers for this precise question.

## Why *hiding* the (child modal) form instead of *closing* it ?

I may be wrong, but I think that in some cases, hidding the modal child form instead of closing it is sometimes useful.

For example, I'm using a class that is a custom tree of grids. Think of something like an Excel Document with multiples tables (sheets) and each table can have child tables. A very powerful manner to store datas that can be used by multiple objects and multiple forms at a time.

Now, this "TreeTable_Class" object has an inbuilt custom form that actually shows the content of one of its tables at a time in a GridView, and you can select which table to show by selecting it in a Treeview. You can see here that the "Database Editor" is actually and MDI Form that can load the Form from any TreeTable_Class.

[image]

And this is the Form I use to edit the content of a Cell for a given (selected) Table (I've chosen another cell with long text content from another table in this database)

[image]

Now, when you choose to close the custom form instead of hiding it, that form will be **unaccessible**, you can't show it anymore, and you get an exception (no instance of the object) Somewhat, it isn't disposed yet (so the check **If MyForm Is Nothing Then...** is useless) I know I have to implement the GarbageCollector and dispose the Child Form manually, but it's outside the scope of this topic.

Anyway, my class could use a large amount of memory, of datas, and if I had to rebuilt ALL the contents each time I want to show a *new* instance of that form, that would be a large amount of workload in my application. That's why I have chosen to **hide** the form instead of **closing** it until the main application exits or when a specific CloseFormAndDispose() method is explicitly called, either by the program, or if I make this option available for the user via an user interface.

## Workaround try :

This is the workaround I've found to override the "*form replaced by another because none of the parent/child ones could be retrieved*" :

**Sorry, I'm in VB..** but you can use a tool to convert this to C#, or do it manually, it's pretty simple..

```
// This is the child, a Cell Editor that can edit the content of a Cell.
Protected WithEvents _CellEditor As CellEditor_Form = Nothing
```

This Editor form is a member of TreeTable_Form, a form that can actually show and edit the content of the whole Database File (a single file)
And this TreeTable_Form class contains a routine that handles CellEditor closing event

```
Public Partial Class TreeTable_Form
    // Sorry. The "WithEvents" in C# is a litte bit complex to me... So, in VB :
    Protected WithEvents _CellEditor As CellEditor_Form = Nothing
    // ...

    // CellEditor handling method (I used a Code converter...) :
    // The original VB declaration is :
    // Protected Sub RecallFormAfterCellEditorHidden() Handles _CellEditor.Closed
    // You'll have to write specific Event handler for _CellEditor object declared above...
    protected void RecallFocusAfterCellEditorHidden()
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        this.Focus();
    }

End Class
```

This tiny **protected void RecallFormAfterCellEditorHidden()** method in your Class (if you are using a class that contains Forms) **or in your Main From**, assuming that your main form contains the child forms (dialogs) **will try to force the focus on your Application or MainForm...**

By the way, TreeTable_**Form** is actually a component of TreeTable_**Class**. The later is an object that can be used anywhere you want. In a Main Form Application, in another Class, in a dialog, anywhere... and could be passed by reference to share its contents between several items. And this TreeTable_Class contains a **RecallFocusAfterTreeViewerHidden()** method that handles the closing of that form. That means, the Form or Application that actually uses the class will get the focus each time you close the its child Form. I've made it that way to get an object that could be used anywhere

## We still get problems !

However, this method will make your application flicker a bit each time you close your child dialog, **and doesn't succeed at 100%** ! Sometimes, my parent form still disappear from screen and gets struck behind another window. Alt+TAB wont helt either. But this happens less than without this method trick. I don't have any better answer at this time, still searching... I'll come back here if I find out how. I'm using this custom made application in my work to write memos during meetings for example, and produce PV (procès verbal - french sorry) in PDF or DOCx on the fly...

And I'm sorry, I'm in VB, not C#. Hope this helps a little, until we find a better workaround for this...